# Multiple join Conditions in Hibernate HQL, while mapping the data instead of in where clause

Tags: hibernate, hql

I am trying to do something like this

Native SQL :

```
Select * 
from FirstTable ft 
   right join SecondTable st on (st.ID=ft.ID and ft.fStatus !='b') where ft.fStatus!='b'
```

In short I just don't want to map `FirstTable` data with `SecondTable` when there is something like this `[ft.fStatus !='b']`. But when this happens I want to have the corresponding record from `SecondTable`.

I searched for this and found `with` keyword , but that was not helpful in my case.
Please look at the sample data below for any reference :

```
FirstTable
   fId  |   fName   |   fStatus
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    1   |   Name1   |     b
    2   |   Name2   |     b
    3   |   Name3   |     a
    2   |   Name4   |     b
    3   |   Name5   |     b
    4   |   Name6   |     a
    4   |   Name7   |     a


SecondTable
   sId  |   sName
+++++++++++++++++++
    1   |   Name1
    2   |   Name2
    3   |   Name3
    4   |   Name4


Expected Output :

   fId   |   fName    |   sId  |   sName   
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    _   |     _       |    1   |   Name1
    _   |     _       |    2   |   Name2
    3   |   Name3     |    3   |   Name3
    4   |   Name6     |    4   |   Name4
    4   |   Name7     |    4   |   Name4
```

Comment: Showing sample data ( a few rows of each table ) and the expected output will be useful to assist you.

Comment: Hi Kaushik Nayak , i have edited my question and provided sample data in both tables and also mentioned the required output. please review the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to Add `oneToMany` mapping in your `Parent Entity` i.e. `SecondTable` for `Child Entity` i.e. `FirstTable`.
For Example :

```
class FirstTable{
    Integer pkColumn;
    SecondTable fId ; 
    String fName ;
    String  fStatus;

    --Getter and Setters
}

class SecondTable{
    Integer sId ; 
    String sName ;

    @oneToManny(mappedBy="fId ")
    List<FirstTable> firstTable;

    --Getter and Setters
}
```

HQL for your expected output:

```
SELECT ft.fId, ft.fName, st.sId, st.sName FROM SecondTable st 
  LEFT JOIN st.firstTable ft WITH ft.fStatus != 'b' 
    WHERE (--other Conditions--)
```